# Callback URL invalid when trying to link my bot on Gupshup

Tags: gupshup

I am trying to link my bot with Gupshup platform. I get an error saying my callback url (ngrok) is not valid even though the URL is valid and I can test the response on my browser. Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to link your bot using a callback URL, Gupshup makes a Get call to the URL provided along with these dummy URL parameters

```
channel=telegram&contextobj={"botname":"demobot1","channeltype":"telegram","contextid":"164772271","contexttype":"p2p"}&senderobj={"channelid":"164772271","channeltype":"telegram","display":"Test"}&messageobj={"text":"hi","type":"msg"}&botname=<yourbotname>
```

Your bot code should respond back with a **200 ok** response for Gupshup to accept it as a valid callback URL.

For example:

If you are developing in Java and have project called **testbot** which contains a servelet like `@WebServlet("/botcode")` then your callback URL with ngork should be:

```
<ngrok https url>/testbot/botcode
```

Sample URL:

```
https://fa3119a4.ngrok.io/testbot/botcode
```